# XSLT Image Source Duplication

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, xslt

I have an XSLT file where I output the image source using an attribute.  It works fine or should I say it was working fine until I realised that it's outputting two values the same that are now stopping the images working.

```
<img class="right" alt="TN">
  <xsl:attribute name="src">
    <xsl:value-of select="@Thumbnail" />
  </xsl:attribute>
</img>
```

The output is as follows:

```
<img class="right" src="images/thumb01.jpg, images/thumb01.jpg" alt="Image">
```

Does anyone know how or why this may be happening?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't duplicates, by default **Image / Link** field has two values. First is **URL**, second is **description**. When description left empty, it automatically fills up same as URL. To prevent displaying description in **src**, you might it cut off.

**So use this:**

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(@Thumbnail, ',')" />
```